# How to remove all inline styling attributes using Moovweb

Tags: moovweb

I have just started a site and it has a lot of in-line styling to clean up.

Is there a short cut way to remove the styling beyond doing it line by line?

eg in html.ts there is a remove_all_styles() - > is this possible to extend to remove_all_inline_styles() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use remove_attributes() to remove all the attributes or remove_class('ClassName') else heir is no such function for removing inline styles

Answer (score 0):

You could add a bit to the `remove_all_styles()` function where you do something like this:

`remove(".//@style")`

This will go through every HTML node child to the current node and remove the style attribute from it.

Comment: Thanks - do you know where these standard funtions are stored.  I am not sure where to update the remove_all_styles.